# Underclared identifier on struct

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

Having two errors with this code on line 4:

'Account' is undeclared identifier
Missing ')' before identifier 'accounts'

Help solving these errors would be great, I have tried but come up short, new to structs

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
const int MAXACCOUNTS = 8;
int interest(Account accounts[], int MAXACCOUNTS);



struct Account
{
int Number;
double Balance;
int DaysSinceDebited;
};

int main()

{
int Accountnumber;
double Balance;
int DaysSinceDebited;
Account accounts[MAXACCOUNTS];

accounts[0].Number = 1001;
accounts[0].Balance = 4254.40;
accounts[0].DaysSinceDebited = 20;

accounts[1].Number = 7940;
accounts[1].Balance = 270006.25;
accounts[1].DaysSinceDebited = 35;

accounts[2].Number = 4382;
accounts[2].Balance = 123.50;
accounts[2].DaysSinceDebited = 2;

accounts[3].Number = 2651;
accounts[3].Balance = 85326.92;
accounts[3].DaysSinceDebited = 14;

accounts[4].Number = 3020;
accounts[4].Balance = 657.0;
accounts[4].DaysSinceDebited = 5;

accounts[5].Number = 7168;
accounts[5].Balance = 7423.34;
accounts[5].DaysSinceDebited = 360;

accounts[6].Number = 6285;
accounts[6].Balance = 4.99;
accounts[6].DaysSinceDebited = 1;

accounts[7].Number = 9342;
accounts[7].Balance = 107964.44;
accounts[7].DaysSinceDebited = 45;




system("pause");
}

int interest(Account accounts[], int MAXACCOUNTS) {

int total = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < MAXACCOUNTS; i++)
{

    if (accounts[i].Balance > 10000 || accounts[i].DaysSinceDebited > 30)
    {
        total = accounts[i].Balance / 100 * 1.06;

        cout << "Account Number: " << accounts[i].Number << "Balance " <<  accounts[i].Balance << "DaysSinceDebited " << accounts[i].DaysSinceDebited <<   endl;
    }

    else
    {
        total = accounts[i].Balance / 100 * 1.03;
        cout << "Account Number: " << accounts[i].Number << "Balance " <<  accounts[i].Balance << "DaysSinceDebited " << accounts[i].DaysSinceDebited << endl;
    }

}
return total;



system("pause");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Account` is not yet declared at the point where you try to use it.

You can simply add a **forward declaration** to make it work:

```
struct Account; // now the compiler knows what Account is
int interest(Account accounts[], int MAXACCOUNTS);
```

Or alternatively, move the declaration of `interest` after the `Account` definition.

Comment: This fixed the errors but my program literally does nothing, damn

Comment: @vaynex maybe you meant to call the `interest` function somewhere